# Can't get response using REST API in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, api, rapidapi

UPDATE: Fix is in the answer!

Please help!

I want to use the Instgram api from RapidApi. This is what RapidAPI shows as the PHP snippet:

```
<?php

$request = new HttpRequest();
$request->setUrl('https://instagram47.p.rapidapi.com/public_user_posts');
$request->setMethod(HTTP_METH_GET);

$request->setQueryData([
    'userid' => '1718924098'
]);

$request->setHeaders([
    'x-rapidapi-key' => ' ***************** ',
    'x-rapidapi-host' => 'instagram47.p.rapidapi.com'
]);

try {
    $response = $request->send();

    echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
```

This is what my code looks like in functions.php:

```
function get_instaPosts(){
    $request = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( 'https://instagram47.p.rapidapi.com/user_posts', array(
            'headers' => array(
                "content-type" => "application/json",
                'userid' => '1718924098',
                'x-rapidapi-key' => 'INSTA_APIKEY',
                'x-rapidapi-host' => 'instagram47.p.rapidapi.com'
            ),
            'body' => array()
            )
        ));

    $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);

    if( 401 === $response_code) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r("Unauthorised access");
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    if( 200 !== $response_code) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r("Error in pinging API");
        echo "</pre>";
    }

    if( 200 === $response_code) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($body);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}
```

But its consistently printing the `"Error in pinging API"` defined in `if (200!==...)` statement. Printing the $response gives this in between:

```
[body] => {"message":"Missing required parameters"}
```

Finally, since they give you a secret API key, is it a good practice to save the actual key as a variable inside wp-config like this and refer it later with just INSTA_APIKEY to not make it public:

```
/** API key for RapidApi Insta */
define( 'INSTA_APIKEY', '***************' );
```

Thanks a lot guys you have no idea how much this platform has helped me. :D

Comment: Rather than change the question, it's worth restoring your original problem and adding the solution (the current content of the question) as an answer.

Comment: @NigelRen I am new to stack exchange. I have updated my OP with the link to the API in question if someone wants to test. Will keep your advice in mind for future. :)

Comment: I would recommend following @NigelRen's guidance with this current question, as well as in the future. Applying these guidelines ensures high-quality content for future visitors to this question that may be having the same issues.

Comment: @RagingVids what Nigel is saying is edit your question to restore it to what didn't work, and then post the working code as an answer. Do not update the question with the working code since it will show as having no answers and will help no one in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIX:
In functions.php:

```
function get_instaPosts(){
    $userid = ' ** insta userid here ** ';
    $first = '2';
    $after = ' ** the after code here ** ';
    $response = wp_remote_get( "https://instagram40.p.rapidapi.com/account-medias?userid=$userid&first=$first&after=$after", array(
            'headers' => array(
                'x-rapidapi-key' => ' ** secret key ** ',
                'x-rapidapi-host' => 'instagram40.p.rapidapi.com'
                )
            )
        );
        

    $response_code = wp_remote_retrieve_response_code($response);
    $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body($response);
    $decode = json_decode( $body, true );
```